# On Brownian motions

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus, dirichlet-forms

I have a question about Brownian motions and its heat kernel.

Using Dirichlet form theory, we can construct Brownian motions on manifolds, domains of Euclidean space under mild assumptions. For example, let $D$ be a domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then, we can define the following bilinear form:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E}(f,g)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{D}(\nabla f, \nabla g)\,dx,\quad f,g \in H^{1}(D),
\end{equation*}
where $H^{1}(D)$ is the Sobolev space of first order (with Neumann boundary condition). Furthermore, if this form is regular on $L^{2}(\bar{D},dx)$, we can construct reflecting Brownian motion on $\bar{D}$. I think Regularity assumption is very mild assumption. For example, when $D$ has continuous boundary, this form is regular.

**My question**

I am interested in estimate of heat kernel $p(t,x,y)$ of reflecting Brownian motion as above. In my research, **the existence is assured by this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200786053) and references therein.** Furthermore, if the Sobolev inequality holds, we can obtain nice (**full time**) estimate like as
\begin{equation}
p(t,x,y) \le a_{1}t^{-d/2} \exp(-|x-y|^{2}/a_{2}t)\cdots(1),
\end{equation}
where $a_1, a_2$ are constants independent of $x,y,t$.

But I don't know nice heat kernel (upper) estimate when the Sobolev inequality is dropped. It is known that if $D$ is expressed as
\begin{align*}
D_{1}=\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_{1}>1, 0<x_{2}<e^{-x_1} \},
\end{align*}
we can prove Sobolev inequality does not hold. This is heat kernel of reflecting Brownian motion $\left\{X^{1}_{t} \right\}$ on $\bar{D}_{1}$ does not have nice estimate as (1).

On the other hand, if $0<t<1$, the sample path of $\left\{X^{1}_{t} \right\}$ is continuous, its heat kernel has nice estimate as (1). That is, I expected that heat kernel of $\left\{X^{1}_{t} \right\}$ has the following estimate:
\begin{equation}
p(t,x,y) \le a_{1}t^{-d/2} \exp(-|x-y|^{2}/a_{2}t),
\end{equation}
for all $x,y \in \bar{D}_{1}$ and $t\in (0,1)$, where $a_1, a_2$ are constants independent of $x,y,t$.

If you know related works on this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not think Sobolev inequality also holds under the same set of regularity assumptions under which the bilinear form is regular (as a bilinear function over the domain $\bar{D}$). For example, consider a weighted Sobolev space which puts exponential weight on the component with exponential growth rate.

The only/authoritative reference I know about the kind of reflecting( I think what you mean is symmetric in standard terminologies) Brownian motions is [Fukushima-Oshima] Sec 2.4, which is devoted to discussion of Sobolev-type inequality. You can reduce the problem to a estimate problem as a Laplacian but I think a necessary condition to give a better estimate is modulus of continuity on the path of ${X_t^1}$ which allows you to integrate along the path w.r.t. the Dirichlet-form.

The paper you cited requires local structure on the space so it is not completely discarding manifold structure, and that is the reason why it has nicer results than your $D_1$ estimate. But on the other hand I think it is possible to obtain local bound and use a compactness argument to extend to the whole space, which will be interesting to know.

[Fukushima-Oshima]Fukushima, Masatoshi, Yoichi Oshima, and Masayoshi Takeda. Dirichlet forms and symmetric Markov processes. Vol. 19. Walter de Gruyter, 2010.